# How to add HTML code in Post Grid in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a wordpress website showing 3 post per row and almost unlimited rows due to ajax autoload for pagination.

What is the best way to add say for example a custom HTML code instead of post every 5th post?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a count to the loop that is pulling the posts into the rows.

for example:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'posts',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) :
$temp_post = $post; ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php $count = 1; foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php //This count adds the custom html mark usful if its only a sinle line of markup.
        echo ( $count % 5 == 0 ) ? '<h2 class="custom-html-markup">Custom Markup</h2>' : ''; ?>

        <?php // If the markup is longer than a single line.
        if ( $count % 5 == 0 ) : ?>
            <div class="custom-html-markup">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php // This count closes and re-opens the rows
        echo ( $count % 3 == 0 ) ? '</div><div class="row">' : ''; ?>
    <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php $post = $temp_post;
endif; ?>
```